# how to configure the listening interface or IP address for geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have multiple network adapters (with virtual IP addresses on each) on my box and I want to run geth on a certain network interface with a certain IP address. How do I do this? Can't find the parameter.

--port is for port only, but where is the --ip option ? (or --device)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this parameter **--rpcaddr YOURVIRTUALIP**.

So if you want to access from another computer on your local network remember to open your virtual IP to your local network.

You can find more information here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/README.md

Regards!

Comment: but I am talking about the RPC API, I am talking about the Wire protocol.

Comment: In this case the interface used is the default network you can use route in linux to see what is it, if you want to change the IP of the enode, you need to change your default network device to the IP that you want. If anyone knows another alternative welcome here :)

Regards!